# What are some examples of using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to understand Nokogiri. Does anyone have a link to a basic example of Nokogiri parse/scrape showing the resultant tree. Think it would really help my understanding.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation / tutorials : http://nokogiri.org/tutorials. This question is a little too general, might get closed ;)

Comment: This information is in the Nokogiri docs. Also, if you'll look through some of the related links to the right side of the page, you'll find examples of using Nokogiri, along with examples of its output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using IRB and Ruby 1.9.2:

Load Nokogiri:

```
> require 'nokogiri'
#=> true
```

Parse a document:

```
> doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body><p>foobar</p></body></html>')
#=> #<Nokogiri::HTML::Document:0x1012821a0
      @node_cache = [],
      attr_accessor :errors = [],
      attr_reader :decorators = nil
```

Nokogiri likes well formed docs. Note that it added the `DOCTYPE` because I parsed as a document. It's possible to parse as a document fragment too, but that is pretty specialized.

```
> doc.to_html
#=> "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body><p>foobar</p></body></html>\n"
```

Search the document to find the first `<p>` node using CSS and grab its content:

```
> doc.at('p').text
#=> "foobar"
```

Use a different method name to do the same thing:

```
> doc.at('p').content
#=> "foobar"
```

Search the document for all `<p>` nodes inside the `<body>` tag, and grab the content of the first one. `search` returns a nodeset, which is like an array of nodes.

```
> doc.search('body p').first.text
#=> "foobar"
```

This is an important point, and one that trips up almost everyone when first using Nokogiri. `search` and its `css` and `xpath` variants return a NodeSet. `NodeSet.text` or `content` concatenates the text of all the returned nodes into a single String which can make it *very* difficult to take apart again.

Using a little different HTML helps illustrate this:

```
> doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body><p>foo</p><p>bar</p></body></html>')
> puts doc.to_html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<p>foo</p>
<p>bar</p>
</body></html>

> doc.search('p').text
#=> "foobar"

> doc.search('p').map(&:text)
#=> ["foo", "bar"]
```

Returning back to the original HTML...

Change the content of the node:

```
> doc.at('p').content = 'bar'
#=> "bar"
```

Emit a parsed document as HTML:

```
> doc.to_html
#=> "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body><p>bar</p></body></html>\n"
```

Remove a node:

```
> doc.at('p').remove
#=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x80939178 name="p" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x8091a624 "bar">]>
> doc.to_html
#=> "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body></body></html>\n"
```

As for scraping, there are a lot of questions on SO about using Nokogiri for tearing apart HTML from sites. Searching StackOverflow for "[nokogiri and open-uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nokogiri+open-uri)" should help.

Comment: Also found good introduction from co-creator: http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/getting-started-with-nokogiri/ also tree diagram mentioned in article can be seen at: http://rubyreflector.com/Data-Structures