# How to access nested XML with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to parse XML. I was told to use a CSS selector to search through the XML, but I can't chain it to get through the nested objects.

How do I access the inner elements?

```
2.6.3 :039 > pp a.css("interface").to_s          
"<interface>\n" +
"    <status>\n" +
"     <__XML__OPT_Cmd_show_interface_status_down>\n" +
"      <__XML__OPT_Cmd_show_interface_status___readonly__>\n" +
"       <__readonly__>\n" +
"        <TABLE_interface>\n" +
"         <ROW_interface>\n" +
"          <interface>mgmt0</interface>\n" +
"          <state>connected</state>\n" +
"          <vlan>routed</vlan>\n" +
"          <duplex>full</duplex>\n" +
"          <speed>a-1000</speed>\n" +
"          <type>--</type>\n" +
"         </ROW_interface>\n" +
"         <ROW_interface>\n" +
"          <interface>Vlan1</interface>\n" +
"          <state>down</state>\n" +
"          <vlan>routed</vlan>\n" +
"          <duplex>auto</duplex>\n" +
"          <speed>auto</speed>\n" +
"         </ROW_interface>\n" +
"         <ROW_interface>\n" +
"          <interface>Vlan6</interface>\n" +
"          <state>down</state>\n" +
"          <vlan>routed</vlan>\n" +
"          <duplex>auto</duplex>\n" +
"          <speed>auto</speed>\n" +
"         </ROW_interface>\n" +
"         <ROW_interface>\n" +
"          <interface>Vlan486</interface>\n" +
"          <state>down</state>\n" +
"          <vlan>routed</vlan>\n" +
"          <duplex>auto</duplex>\n" +
"          <speed>auto</speed>\n" +
"         </ROW_interface>\n" +
"        </TABLE_interface>\n" +
"       </__readonly__>\n" +
"      </__XML__OPT_Cmd_show_interface_status___readonly__>\n" +
"     </__XML__OPT_Cmd_show_interface_status_down>\n" +
"    </status>\n" +
"   </interface><interface>mgmt0</interface><interface>Vlan1</interface><interface>Vlan6</interface><interface>Vlan486</interface>"
```

I end up with this tree. What is my XPath here? This is only part of the parsed XML:

```
2.6.3 :043 > pp parsed
#(DocumentFragment:0x3fce080cd300 {
  name = "#document-fragment",
  children = [
    #(ProcessingInstruction:0x3fce080cce14 { name = "xml" }),
    #(Text "\n"),
    #(Element:0x3fce080cc7d4 {
      name = "rpc-reply",
      namespace = #(Namespace:0x3fce080cffb0 {
        prefix = "nf",
        href = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0"
        }),
      children = [
        #(Text "\n" + " "),
        #(Element:0x3fce080cf22c {
          name = "data",
          namespace = #(Namespace:0x3fce080cffb0 {
            prefix = "nf",
            href = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0"
            }),
          children = [
            #(Text "\n" + "  "),
            #(Element:0x1903f98 {
              name = "show",
              namespace = #(Namespace:0x1903f20 {
                href = "http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:if_manager"
                }),
              children = [
                #(Text "\n" + "   "),
                #(Element:0x1903700 {
                  name = "interface",
                  namespace = #(Namespace:0x1903f20 {
                    href = "http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:if_manager"
                    }),
                  children = [
                    #(Text "\n" + "    "),
                    #(Element:0x19030fc {
                      name = "status",
                      namespace = #(Namespace:0x1903f20 {
                        href = "http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:if_manager"
                        }),
                  children = [
                    #(Text "\n" + "     "),
                    #(Element:0x1902a1c {
                      name = "__XML__OPT_Cmd_show_interface_status_down",
                      namespace = #(Namespace:0x1903f20 {
                        href = "http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:if_manager"
                        }),
```

Comment: We need to know what node your are searching for, and what accessor you're using to try to find it. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and use the information there as a guide to improving your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really generic and poorly asked so answering a specific question is not possible, but it looks like you need to understand how to access tags in a document using a CSS accessor, which Nokogiri makes very easy.

Meditate on this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

foo =<<EOT
<tag1>
  <tag2>some text</tag2>
  <tag3>some more text</tag3>
  <tags>something</tags>
  <tags>or</tags>
  <tags>other</tags>
</tag1>
EOT

xml = Nokogiri::XML.parse(foo)
```

`at` finds the first matching occurrence in the document:

```
xml.at('tag2').content # => "some text"
```

[`at`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#at-instance_method) is pretty smart, in that it tries to determine whether the accessor is CSS or XPath, so it's a good first tool when you want the *first* match. If that doesn't work then you can try [`at_css`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable.html#at_css-instance_method) which specifies that accessor is CSS, because sometimes you can come up with something that could work as CSS or XPath but return different results:

```
xml.at_css('tag3').content # => "some more text"
xml.at_css('tag3').text # => "some more text"
```

Similar to `at` is [`search`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable.html#search-instance_method), which also tries to determine whether it's CSS or XPath, but finds all matching nodes throughout the document rather than just the first matching one. Because it returns all matching nodes, it returns a NodeSet, unlike `at` which returns a Node, so you have to be aware that NodeSets behave differently than Nodes when accessing their `content` or `text`:

```
xml.search('tags').text # => "somethingorother"
```

That's almost never what you want, but you'd be surprised how many people then ask how to split that resulting string into the desired three words. It's usually impossible to do accurately, so a different tactic is needed:

```
xml.search('tags').map { |t| t.content } # => ["something", "or", "other"]
xml.search('tags').map { |t| t.text } # => ["something", "or", "other"]
xml.search('tags').map(&:text) # => ["something", "or", "other"]
```

Both `at` and `search` have `..._css` and `..._xpath` variations to help you fine-tune your code's behavior, but I always recommend starting with the generic `at` and `search` until you're forced to define what the accessor is.

I also recommend starting with CSS accessors over XPath because they tend to be more readable, and more easily learned if you're working inside HTML with CSS. XPath is very powerful, probably still more so than CSS, but learning it takes longer and often results in less readable code, which affects maintainability.

This is all in the [tutorials and cheat sheets](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet) and [documentation](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/index.html). Nokogiri is extremely powerful but it takes time reading and trying things to learn it. You can also [search on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A128421%20nokogiri) for other things I've written about searching XML and HTML documents; In particular "[What are some examples of using Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482543/what-are-some-examples-of-using-nokogiri/8482746#8482746)" helps get an idea how to scrape a page. There's a lot of information covering many different topics related to this. I find it an interesting exercise to parse documents like this as it was part of my professional life for years.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xpath`:

```rb
parsed = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(xml)
siamese_cat = parsed.xpath(.//interface/status/state)
```

Or just iterating thru XML

```rb
parsed = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(xml)
parsed.each do |element|
   # Some instructions
end
```

Comment: i added some more output. I dont really get what i have to add as my xpath

Comment: Almost never do we want to use `each` on a document to iterate over every node. If nothing else, it results in much slower code as you walk the nodes, plus write a lot of code trying to determine if you're on a node you want. Instead, Using `at`, `search`, `css`, `xpath` or one of their variants is much faster and results in less code. `each` is useful when you are analyzing a document or can't get to a particular place in the document any other way.